# Getting error in Taleo web service call in Java web application

Tags: java, maven, web-services, wsdl, eclipse-luna

Eclipse: Luna 4.4.2
Tomcate 8.0
Attaching my POM.xml

I want to call taleo webservice and trying to create a dynamic web application.
I tried following scenarios:
Scenario 1: wsdl is working fine in SOAP UI.

Scenario 2:
Created a maven project and generate the source for wsdl and write the code for client.Able to call the webservice without any error And create java UI (Frame) and show the result on UI.

Scenario 3:
Created a maven project, add the wsdl into it and generate source for wsdl. Then trying to convert it into web application Getting below error:
cannot nest '31JanTest/target/generated-sources/cxf/schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans' inside '31JanTest/target/generated-sources/cxf'. To enable the nesting exclude 'schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans/' from '31JanTest/target/generated-sources/cxf'.

Scenarion 4:
Step 1:
(First created dynamic web application then convert it to a maven project). As soon as i added wsdl to this project getting below error in wsdl:

```
src-resolve.4.2: Error resolving component 'ns2:Entity'. It was detected that 'ns2:Entity' is in namespace 'http://www.taleo.com/
 ws/tee800/2009/01', but components from this namespace are not referenceable from schema document 'file:///C:/Users/
 deepak_gupta22/WorkSpace1/test123/src/taleoWebservice.wsdl'. If this is the incorrect namespace, perhaps the prefix of 
 'ns2:Entity' needs to be changed. If this is the correct namespace, then an appropriate 'import' tag should be added to 'file:///C:/
 Users/deepak_gupta22/WorkSpace1/test123/src/taleoWebservice.wsdl'.
 Step 2:
 Ignore this error in wsdl and build the application and wrote the client code and run the application. I got below error:
 SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [main.MyTestServlet] in context with path [/test123] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2496)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:860)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1302)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2902)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1615)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.processClass(RuntimeModeler.java:462)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.buildRuntimeModel(RuntimeModeler.java:305)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.<init>(DatabindingImpl.java:85)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.DatabindingProviderImpl.create(DatabindingProviderImpl.java:59)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.DatabindingProviderImpl.create(DatabindingProviderImpl.java:43)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.DatabindingFactoryImpl.createRuntime(DatabindingFactoryImpl.java:105)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.buildRuntimeModel(WSServiceDelegate.java:875)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.createSEIPortInfo(WSServiceDelegate.java:892)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.addSEI(WSServiceDelegate.java:855)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:435)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:404)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:386)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:119)
    at com.taleo.ws.tee800._2009._01.find.FindService.getFindServiceHttpPort(FindService.java:72)
    at main.ClientService.getEntities(ClientService.java:202)
    at main.MyTestServlet.doGet(MyTestServlet.java:42)
```

What am I missing in web application or what i have to add in web application to work it properly?

I can see in java project below two folders are created automatically:
1. target/generated-sources/cxf
2. target/generated-sources/cxf/schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans

But in web project only one folder is created:
1. target/generated-sources/cxf

target/generated-sources/cxf/schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans forlder is not created in web project. Please help me what is wrong in my project?

Experts please help me to resolve the issue.
Pleaase let me know if more information needed from my side.

Thanks and Regards,
Deepak

Answer (score 0):

In the marker tab. i was getting "Classpath entry org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER will not be exported or published. Runtime ClassNotFoundExceptions may result" warning.

I Resolved it by doing following steps:
 1. Right click on this warning and click on quick fix option
 2. Select Mark the associated raw classpath entry as a publish/export dependency. And click on finish